# Why is this non-greedy regex grabbing more than I want?

Tags: java, regex, non-greedy

I would think this should return "state,country" but it's returning "country"

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceAll("(.*,)?", ""));
```

Why is it working this way, and how do I make it return "state,country".  I want this answer as a regex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. if you want to make `.*` to be non-greedy you need to add `?` right after `*`.
2. `replaceAll` will replace all occurrences of matching parts, so you should probably use `replaceFirst`

try

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceFirst(".*?,", ""));
```

output:

```
state,country
```

---

If you can't use `replaceFirst` and need to stay with `replaceAll` then [@Reimeus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285804/1393766) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: This will work if replaceFirst is only used, but otherwise will wipe out city and state.

Comment: @0A0D I am not sure what you are trying to say. Could you explain it more?

Comment: It will match `city,state,` then replace it with nothing and just give him `country`.. I think: http://regexr.com?34nck

if you use replaceAll

Comment: @0A0D Yes this regex will match `city,` and `state,` but `replaceFirst` will only replace first match, so `city,` will be replaced with `""` and `state,` will be unchanged.

Comment: Yep, if you use replaceFirst :) .. other answerers were using replaceAll

Comment: @0A0D OK, so there is nothing wrong with my answer. I am just curious why I got -1. Probably some accident :)

Comment: I'd like the answer to use `replaceAll` because I can see being in situations where I couldn't use `replaceFirst`

Comment: @tieTYT then you should add `^` anchor at start of regex to show that matching part must be placed at start of the input string, just like Reimeus showed in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

As the name suggests, `replaceAll` replaces all matching groups. You need to be more specific where the group is matched. To specify the first matching group you can specify the start of `String` `^` as an anchor:

```
"city,state,country".replaceAll("^(.*?,)", "")
```

Answer (score 4):

You're capturing any group ending in a comma, not just one and that's why it doesn't currently work.

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceAll("^[^,]*+,", ""));
```

Comment: +1 - Nice use of negated character classes as an alternate to reluctant qualifier.

Comment: Agreed with @Alex, that's a nice aspect of your answer to point out. You can go farther and make it a "possessive" greedy match, i.e. `^[^,]*+,` which indicates that backtracking will never be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The ? non-greedy flag can only be used after a + or *, in your context, it is a 0-or-1 match.

You want

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceAll("(.*?,)", ""));
```

Comment: This will wipe out city,state.. he wants to retain state,country

Answer (score 1):

Try with this expression:

```
^(.*?,)
```

or like that:

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceAll("(.*?,)((?:.*?,)+)", "$2"));
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. I did learn from this answer that group references are accepted on the replacement side, +1 from me.